# sed replacement variable has a double backslash, but will not write properly

Tags: bash, sed

In a bash script I am working on to manipulate some configuration files, I have several fields working properly but one field that can take a double backslash `config_item = "configfoo\\configbar"` as part of the configuration string.

I am reading in from the user with `read -rp 'Configuration Item: ' config_item`

Where it echos properly `configfoo\\configbar`

I've been unable to successfully land that into the sed command that updates the file.

```
sed -i -e '/config_item=/ s/=.*/='\"$config_item\"'/' ${dir}/.env
```

I get an error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown command: `\'
```

Which I assume is related to the 1st slash escaping. I've tried four slashes also trying to figure this out.

How do I tell sed to replace with the variable exactly as the user types it, or is there an alternative string preperation step I need to do so that my configuration file line reads

```
config_item = "configfoo\\configbar"
```

There are hundreds of posts on the topic, but I am not trying to substitute the slashes. I just need the string to flow into the substitution.

Comment: I think you mean *back*slashes.  Slashes `/` go bottom left to top right - like in the paths of URLs and normal operating systems (also works in windows fwiw).  *back*slashes \ go top left to bottom right, and are generally used for escape sequences eg `\n` `\r\n` or `"\""`

Comment: @erik258 I missed it in the title, but the thrust of the question remains the same.

Comment: I don't understand "I am not trying to escape them." Don't you want the string escaped so `sed` understands it?

Comment: Perhaps my wording is just confusing on that one, single, very specific line. I don't want the backslash to escape, I just want it to be part of the substituted string. I think the rest of the question explains what I am trying to do though.

Comment: When I used the 'ESCAPED_REPLACE' method in that question (I'm not 100% sure what I needed to implement or not, there is a lot going on there). My input was configfoo\\configbar. When I printed 'ESCAPED_REPLACE' it gave me configfoo\\\\configbar and errored out in the same way.

Comment: nothing wrong with that, `sed -i -e '/config_item=/ s/=.*/="configfoo\\\\configbar"/' "$dir"/.env` is the correct expression for what you want to do; now that you got a variable  with `configfoo\\\\configbar` then you just have to use it correctly with double quotes: `sed -i -e '/config_item=/ s/=.*/="'"$escaped_config_item"'"/' "$dir"/.env`

Comment: @Fravadona that was the winner if you want to update  your answer to that. I had to `sed -i -e '/config_item=/ s/=.*/='\""$ESCAPED_REPLACE"\"'/' ${dir}/.env` . I suppose, when I said I didn't want to escape them, it was that I wanted them to print. I suppose that level of dumb on my part comes from thrashing on it for too long and sifting through pages of documentation and other SO posts.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely don't want to escape your input string then you cannot use `sed`; `awk` is able to do it though:

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "="
        value = ARGV[2]
        delete ARGV[2]
    }
    $1 == "config_item" { $0 = $1 OFS "\"" value "\"" }
    1
' "$dir"/.env "$config_item" > "$dir"/.env.tmp &&
mv "$dir"/.env.tmp "$dir"/.env
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
read -rp 'Configuration Item: ' config_item
export config_item
sed -Ei '/config_item\s*=/s/(.*=\s*).*/printf '\''\1"%s"'\'' "$config_item"/e' file
```

Read input into config_item variable.

Export config_item_variable.

Replace the entire line containing `config_item =`  and replace by `config_item =`  and the bash variable config_item.